# Utilizando GxTest, para automatizar una prueba, al correr la prueba no me ejecuta algunas acciones detalladas en el Script

Tags: genexus

Me encuentro realizando pruebas con GXtest, teniendo en cuenta que los desarrollos los realizamos utilizando Genexus.
Al correr la prueba, el sistema no me reconoce algunos comandos, como por ejemplo hacer clic en algunos botones.
Les comparto mi código, si me pueden ayudar, se los voy a agradecer.

```
// Script generated using GXtest Recorder

//Start webdriver
&driver.Start()
&driver.Maximize()

// Initial navigation
&driver.Go("https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")

&driver.Click("&username")
&driver.Type("&username","xxxxxxxxxx")
&driver.Click("&userpassword")
&driver.Type("&userpassword","xxxxxxxxxxxx")
&driver.Click("login")
&driver.PauseFor(6)
&driver.ClickByName("BTNTOGGLEMENU_MPAGE")
&driver.ClickByCSS("span.sidebar-nav-item")
&driver.ClickByLinkText("Personas")
&driver.ClickByLinkText("Administración de Personas")
&driver.SwitchFrame("index=0")
&driver.Click("&k2btoolsgenericsearchfield")
&driver.Type("&k2btoolsgenericsearchfield","20328527410")
&driver.PauseFor(6)
&driver.Click("&update",1)
&driver.SwitchFrame("index=0")
&driver.ClickByID("PSNCARACTER01")
&driver.TypeByID("PSNCARACTER01","4744444")
&driver.Click("enter")
&driver.SwitchFrame("relative=parent")
AssertStringEquals("La personas fisicas xxxx fue actualizada",&driver.GetTextByCSS("div.toast-message"),"'div.toast-message' not matching La personas fisicas xxxx fue actualizada")
&driver.SwitchFrame("relative=parent")
&driver.ClickByCSS("div.row:nth-child(2) > div.col-xs-12")
&driver.ClickByLinkText("Salir")
&driver.End()

La línea del código que no ejecuta dicho comando es la siguiente

&driver.ClickByID("PSNCARACTER01")
&driver.TypeByID("PSNCARACTER01","4744444")
```

El código debería escribir ese número, pero no lo hace.

Quedo a disposición y agradecería me puedan ayudar.

Gracias